# Suspicious activity between users

Tags: discussion, users, abuse

Some of my answers were unaccepted today. Look at this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695432/error-delete-data-mysql-from-shell-script

My answer was accepted on September 26th. Now another user added [a bad answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40126411/3636601), which is wrong and has no explanation. As I looked at other questions and answers of both users, I can see that the users often accept each others answers. Mostly the answers are worse than the other, earlier answers.

So, I think there is a relationship between these users.

Should I mention something like that to the moderators? If so, how?

Comment: Definitely something fishy going on there.

Comment: If you see something fishy always flag. Worst thing that can happen is that you got a declined flag.

Comment: the OP who posted the question got his account suspended. The system worked :)

Comment: Interesting... This answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/37326649/717214 was unacceptable yesterday in lieu of another, in my view worse quality answer. I can't see the original any more, so can't say if it's the same user.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is no need to call anyone out based on your suspicions. Simply flag one of the posts and use the "needs moderator attention" option to explain what it is you're seeing. Give as much helpful information as possible.

Then, let the moderators do what they're supposed to do.

Answer (score 33):

This situation has been addressed appropriately. As [Aʟ E. said in a perfectly correct answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336561/2057919), in the future, you should just flag an affected post using the "needs moderator attention" option. The more information you can provide, the better.

Please note: while moderators can clean up inappropriate behavior, we cannot make anyone accept an answer. Even though, in this situation, a user accepted good answers, then unaccepted them in favor of low-quality answers, we cannot force the user to re-accept the better, earlier answers.

Unfortunately, when people cheat, it hurts innocent third parties, like everyone who posted good answers to the offending user's questions. That's why we put a stop to it whenever we can.

Comment: A mod couldn't forcibly re-accept the old answer, for sure, but would they not be able to forcibly unaccept the new low quality answer if they were able to demonstrate voting fraud?

Comment: @Servy A mod can't unaccept the new, low-quality answer, but a dev can. Sometimes, we ask for that. More often, if it really is a case of voting fraud, the answers are so VLQ that we just delete them. They're usually just copy-pasta from the question or other answers, so we just nuke them. That's what happened here.

Comment: @Servy - Typically, I just delete them, even if they are decent-looking answers. The accept vote pins them above others, and I've seen numerous cases where outright wrong or dangerous answers were locked there due to fraud like this. We can't trust the voting, so we can't trust that these should be pinned at the top.

Comment: @BradLarson Indeed, I would expect that under no circumstances would the acceptance stay (as it was determined to be fraudulent).  I did assume that it would usually merit deletion, but that it would *always* merit removal of acceptance.  Deleting them isn't something I have a problem with.

Comment: @Servy - The reputation for accept votes is removed when votes are invalidated by SE employees or when users are removed. Perhaps the same situations should also remove the accept status and mark. That would avoid giving moderators power to change these votes while addressing the core problem.

Comment: @BradLarson Sounds like that's merited.  Want me to post a proposal or are you just going to pass it on?

Comment: I second everything that @BradLarson said. If you post a proposal, probably better on MSE, rather than MSO, so mods on other sites can weigh in more easily.

Comment: @BradLarson [Here is the proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286040/186381).

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks for the answer. My aim is not getting back the Reputation or the "accept" sign. My am is only to stop behaviers like that. Esspecially acception VLQ answers. Because that is not helpfull for futher readers.

Comment: *"In the future, you should just [contact us via a means with a strict character limit and no formatting instead of a Meta post]. ... The more information you can provide, the better."* - realistically, you ain't gonna be able to do both of these, are you?

Comment: @MarkAmery That's the best way to do it because (1) it actually gets guaranteed mod attention, which doesn't always happen with a Meta post, and (2) it avoids public shaming of the potentially innocent. And we don't need a ton of information; just enough to know which accounts to look at and why. We actually get a fair number of helpful flags like this, so it's doable.